# ggplot does not show up on my R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, reactive

I am struggling to figure out how to make the plot reactive. The point of my code is you select a radio button with your team where each team is its own dataset buy they all have the same variables. I understand that I could merge all of them together but I am worried that would slow down the speed of the application itself, also if I were to continue working on this and add specific player stats then I believe my current method is the proper way.

I can print the table easily outside of the shiny app but not in it.

So, overall, the code runs but the plot does not show up and I think I have been looking at it too long and am possibly overlooking a potentially simple error.

The datasets I am using come from NBAsavant.com
([link to 76ers team data](https://www.nbasavant.com/shot_search.php?hfST=&hfQ=&hfSZB=&hfSZA=&hfSZR=&ddlYear=2017&txtGameDateGT=&txtGameDateLT=&ddlGameTimeGT_min=&ddlGameTimeGT_sec=&ddlGameTimeLT_min=&ddlGameTimeLT_sec=&ddlShotDistanceGT=&ddlShotDistanceLT=&ddlTeamShooting=&ddlTeamDefense=&hfPT=&ddlGroupBy=team&ddlOrderBy=shots_made_desc&hfGT=0%7C&ddlShotMade=&ddlMin=0#results))

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(rsconnect)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(RCurl)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("NBA 2017-2018 Season: Shooting Analysis"),
  
  fluidRow(
    
    column(2,
      
      radioButtons(inputId = "radio", label = "Select NBA Team",
                   choices = c("76ers", "Bucks", "Bulls",
                                "Cavaliers", "Celtics", "Clippers",
                                "Grizzlies","Hawks","Heat",
                                "Hornets","Jazz","Kings",
                                "Knicks","Lakers","Magic",
                                "Mavericks","Nets","Nuggets",
                                "Pacers","Pelicans","Pistons",
                                "Raptors","Rockets","Spurs",
                                "Suns","Thunder","Timberwolves",
                                "Trail Blzers","Warriors","Wizards"),
                   selected = "76ers")
      ),
    
    fluidRow(10,
      box(width = 10,
              plotOutput("court_plot")))
  )
)

Server <- function(input, output) {
  
   TeamNBA <- reactive({
     if (input$radio == "76ers")
       SeventySixers
     else if (input$radio == "Bucks")
       Bucks
     else if (input$radio == "Bulls")
       Bulls
     else if (input$radio == "Cavaliers")
       Cavaliers
     else if (input$radio == "Celtics")
       Celtics
     else if (input$radio == "Clippers")
       Clippers
     else if (input$radio == "Grizzlies")
       Grizzlies
     else if (input$radio == "Hawks")
       Hawks
     else if (input$radio == "Heat")
       Heat
     else if (input$radio == "Hornets")
       Hornets
     else if (input$radio == "Jazz")
       Jazz
     else if (input$radio == "Kings")
       Kings
     else if (input$radio == "Knicks")
       Knicks
     else if (input$radio == "Lakers")
       Lakers
     else if (input$radio == "Magic")
       Magic
     else if (input$radio == "Mavericks")
       Mavericks
     else if (input$radio == "Nets")
       Nets
     else if (input$radio == "Nuggets")
       Nuggets
     else if (input$radio == "Pacers")
       Pacers
     else if (input$radio == "Pelicans")
       Pelicans
     else if (input$radio == "Pistons")
       Pistons
     else if (input$radio == "Raptors")
       Raptors
     else if (input$radio == "Rockets")
       Rockets
     else if (input$radio == "Spurs")
       Spurs
     else if (input$radio == "Suns")
       Suns
     else if (input$radio == "Thunder")
       Thunder
     else if (input$radio == "Timberwolves")
       Timberwolves
     else if (input$radio == "Trail Blazers")
       TrailBlazers
     else if (input$radio == "Warriors")
       Warriors
     else if (input$radio == "Wizards")
       Wizards
   })


  output$court_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    courtImg <- "http://robslink.com/SAS/democd54/nba_court_dimensions.jpg"
    court <- rasterGrob(readJPEG(getURLContent(courtImg)),
                    width=unit(1, "npc"), height=unit(1, "npc"))
    
    court_plot <- ggplot(TeamNBA, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      annotation_custom(court, -250, 250, -50, 420) +
           geom_hex(bins = 50, alpha = .8) +
        scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis") +
           xlim(-250, 250) +
           ylim(-50, 420)
    
    print(court_plot)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: A reactive value is just a function. To use its actual data, it needs to be evaluated. Therefore, try `TeamNBA()` in your `ggplot` call.

Comment: @starja tried that, and added a team name in as well and still did not work.

Comment: also replace `print(court_plot)` with `court_plot`, you just should return the plot to the output, not directly print it

Comment: @starja did not work either

Comment: Following @starja's suggestions, changing `Server` to `server`, adding some random example data and removing the `box()` statement around plotOutput your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: @stefan I followed both yours and starja's advice and when I run on my machine I get the radio buttons on the left side of the screen but a large blank space for the court_plot...is that what you get or does the court_plot show up and is interactive between teams?

Comment: I just checked with some real data (Bucks & 76ers) and everything works fine. The court_plot shows up with positions as nice hex plots. And yes. It's interactive switching the team gives a new plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide the data, I used the good old `mtcars` as an example.

Issues in the code:

- `server`/`Server` (R is case sensitive)
- a reactive dataset has to be called with brackets: `TeamNBA()`
- `scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis")` uses a variable probably not in the dataset (sounds like from the `iris` dataset), so I removed it
- at the end of the `renderPlot`, don't use `print`
- remove the `box` in the `ui` function

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(RCurl)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("NBA 2017-2018 Season: Shooting Analysis"),
  
  fluidRow(
    
    column(2,
           
           radioButtons(inputId = "radio", label = "Select NBA Team",
                        choices = c("76ers", "Bucks", "Bulls",
                                    "Cavaliers", "Celtics", "Clippers",
                                    "Grizzlies","Hawks","Heat",
                                    "Hornets","Jazz","Kings",
                                    "Knicks","Lakers","Magic",
                                    "Mavericks","Nets","Nuggets",
                                    "Pacers","Pelicans","Pistons",
                                    "Raptors","Rockets","Spurs",
                                    "Suns","Thunder","Timberwolves",
                                    "Trail Blzers","Warriors","Wizards"),
                        selected = "76ers")
    ),
    
    fluidRow(10,
             
                 plotOutput("court_plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  TeamNBA <- reactive({
    if (input$radio == "76ers")
      mtcars
    else if (input$radio == "Bucks")
      Bucks
    else if (input$radio == "Bulls")
      Bulls
    else if (input$radio == "Cavaliers")
      Cavaliers
    else if (input$radio == "Celtics")
      Celtics
    else if (input$radio == "Clippers")
      Clippers
    else if (input$radio == "Grizzlies")
      Grizzlies
    else if (input$radio == "Hawks")
      Hawks
    else if (input$radio == "Heat")
      Heat
    else if (input$radio == "Hornets")
      Hornets
    else if (input$radio == "Jazz")
      Jazz
    else if (input$radio == "Kings")
      Kings
    else if (input$radio == "Knicks")
      Knicks
    else if (input$radio == "Lakers")
      Lakers
    else if (input$radio == "Magic")
      Magic
    else if (input$radio == "Mavericks")
      Mavericks
    else if (input$radio == "Nets")
      Nets
    else if (input$radio == "Nuggets")
      Nuggets
    else if (input$radio == "Pacers")
      Pacers
    else if (input$radio == "Pelicans")
      Pelicans
    else if (input$radio == "Pistons")
      Pistons
    else if (input$radio == "Raptors")
      Raptors
    else if (input$radio == "Rockets")
      Rockets
    else if (input$radio == "Spurs")
      Spurs
    else if (input$radio == "Suns")
      Suns
    else if (input$radio == "Thunder")
      Thunder
    else if (input$radio == "Timberwolves")
      Timberwolves
    else if (input$radio == "Trail Blazers")
      TrailBlazers
    else if (input$radio == "Warriors")
      Warriors
    else if (input$radio == "Wizards")
      Wizards
  })
  
  
  output$court_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    courtImg <- "http://robslink.com/SAS/democd54/nba_court_dimensions.jpg"
    court <- rasterGrob(readJPEG(getURLContent(courtImg)),
                        width=unit(1, "npc"), height=unit(1, "npc"))
    
    court_plot <- ggplot(TeamNBA(), aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) +
      annotation_custom(court, -250, 250, -50, 420) +
      geom_hex(bins = 50, alpha = .8) +
      xlim(-250, 250) +
      ylim(-50, 420)
    
    court_plot
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note: I changed the `aes` to work with `mtcars`, you have to adapt it

Comment: There must be something wrong on my end because after following your advice, I still am unable to see the plot on my screen or when I open the dashboard in my browser.

Comment: sorry, without more information I don't know where the error is; my example above works

Comment: I understand, Thank you!